# Physical Buttons Unresponsive After screenBrightness set to 0

Tags: java, android, screen

I have set LayoutParams.screenBrightness to 0 which turns the screen off in the following code:

```
public void screenOff() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
    params.screenBrightness = 0;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}
```

After running the above code, all hardware buttons become unresponsive (I'm testing on a Galaxy S3). If I press the power button twice then the screen comes back on. In fact, the home button or power button work after the power button is pressed once (therefore, pressing the power button twice will turn on the screen).

I thought it may have been because I used the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, but the same thing happens regardless of the whether I remove that line or not.

Any ideas on why this is this happening and how to fix it?